# Multiple actions were found that match the request: (Get and Download) methods

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've seen this question asked a few times on here, but none of the answers seem to be working for my case.

I have three GET methods on my web api controller, and I also want to add POST/PUT/DELETE methods on here as well.

- GET #1 - A query method that reads parameters from the querystring
- GET #2 - Returns a single object based on it's entity id.
- GET #3 - Downloads the attached file for that object and finds the object based on its entity id.
- Also need to make sure the routes will be able to handle POST/PUT/DELETE calls as well.

See controller code here:

```
public PagedResult<ApiStudentNote> Get([FromUri] StudentNoteApiCriteria criteria)

public ApiStudentNote Get(long id)

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Download")]
public HttpResponseMessage Download(long id)
```

I'm trying to configure the routing as such, but still getting the error mentioned in the title:

```
context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "V2/DownloadStudentNotes",
    routeTemplate: areaName + "/V2/student-notes/{id}/Download",
    defaults: new { controller = "StudentNotes", action = "Download" },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" });

context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "V2/StudentNotesApi",
    routeTemplate: areaName + "/V2/student-notes/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "StudentNotes", id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Check the order of how you are doing your mapping. Put `/V2/student-notes/{id}/Download` mapping before `/V2/student-notes/{id}`

Comment: what is the value of `areaName`. I completely missed that variable when I provided my answer. Which could explain why it didn't work for you

Comment: areaName is just "Api", but I tried with that in the top of the controller

Comment: Changing the order now too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET Web API 2+ you can fix this problem by using Attribute Routing. It will allow you more flexibility.

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

> Why Attribute Routing?
>
> The first release of Web API used convention-based routing. In that
>   type of routing, you define one or more route templates, which are
>   basically parameterized **strings**. When the framework receives a
>   request, it matches the URI against the route template.
>
> One advantage of convention-based routing is that templates are
>   defined in a single place, and the routing rules are applied
>   consistently across all controllers. Unfortunately, convention-based
>   routing makes it hard to support certain URI patterns that are common
>   in RESTful APIs. For example, resources often contain child resources:
>   Customers have orders, movies have actors, books have authors, and so
>   forth. It’s natural to create URIs that reflect these relations:
>
> /customers/1/orders
>
> This type of URI is difficult to create using convention-based
>   routing. Although it can be done, the results don’t scale well if you
>   have many controllers or resource types.
>
> With attribute routing, it’s trivial to define a route for this URI.
>   You simply add an attribute to the controller action:

configure the routing as such

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Other Web API configuration not shown.
    }
}
```

controller code here:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v2/student-notes")]
public class StudentNotesController : ApiController {

    // GET api/v2/student-notes
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public PagedResult<ApiStudentNote> GetNotes([FromUri] StudentNoteApiCriteria criteria) {...}

    // GET api/v2/student-notes/1234567
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:long}")]
    public ApiStudentNote GetNote(long id) {...}

    // GET api/v2/student-notes/1234567/Download
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:long}/Download")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Download(long id) {...}

}
```

The [Route Constraints](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints) were added because in the template

> api/v2/student-notes/{id}

The following URIs would match this template:

- `api/v2/student-notes/1234` where id => 1234
- `api/v2/student-notes/1234/Download` where id => 1234/Download

which would reflect the multiple matches you were originally having with your convention-based routes.

Comment: Just tried this, but I get a 404 on the first method.  Do I need to register anything in the route configs? I also changed the route prefix to "api/v2/student-notes" and that didn't work either.

Comment: Make sure your parameters match the properties of the `StudentNoteApiCriteria ` in order for it to be mapped properly

Comment: @Nikosi -- yeah I have had this working prior to adding the Download method, so I know the criteria method does work.  Going through that article now as well.

Comment: Everything works just fine as soon as I remove the Download method.  I don't need any fancy routing or [attribute] decorations on any of the methods. Just a very simple route config.  Quite frustrating.

Comment: Well in that case then, remove the `id = RouteParameter.Optional` from your  original route mapping. `Get(long id)` and `Download(long id)` Both match the first mapping, hence the error

Comment: So now the first method (with criteria) works but the second method does not since both the Get(long id) and Download(long id) break, as you mentioned.  So it's really trying to figure out how to get the second and third method to play nice together.

Comment: I believe its the ordering as well as the optional id.

Comment: I will post above what I currently have, but I definitely still get that same error.  Let me update it now.  Right now I am not using any of the attributes you recommended in the actual controller class.  Trying again with those added back.

Comment: Using that route config along with those attributes in the controller results in a 405 in the criteria method.  I have to run right now but will return in 1 hour.  Thanks so much for your guidance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you use Web API 2 or above. If so, you do not need any convention based routing in `WebApiConfig`. All you need is enable attribute routing instead and decorate your methods:

```
public static class WebApiConfig 
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // No route config needed beyond this point.

    }
}

[RoutePrefix("api/v2/student-notes")]
public class StudentNotesController : ApiController 
{
    public PagedResult<ApiStudentNote> GetNotes(
        [FromUri] StudentNoteApiCriteria criteria)
    {
        //...
    }

    [Route("{id}", Name="GetNote")] 
    public ApiStudentNote GetNote(long id)
    {
        //...
    }

    [Route("{id}/Download")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Download(long id)
    {
        //...
    }

    // in future scenarios this will work as well
    public ApiStudentNote PostNote(ApiStudentNote studentNote)
    {
        // persist new student note
        return CreatedAt("GetNote", new {id = studentNote.Id }, studentNote);
    }

    [Route("{id}")]
    public ApiStudentNote PutNote(ApiStudentNote studentNote)
    {
        // retrieve
        // update
        // persist
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I did not decorate the methods with `HttpGet` or the like because the routing service can infer the HTTP method from method names (`GetNote` infers `GET`, `PostNote` infers `POST`). For clarity however you could add the attributes.

About the named route on the `GetNote` method. I added that to show you how you in future scenarios can implement `POST` and how you can return the location of the newly created note in a `Location` header. `ApiController.CreatedAt` can do that for you if you provide the name of the route.